# i want cell data from grid view and check that value is greater than the text box value at the time of insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net

get value from grid view and store in a variable and check the condition of variable value is greater than text box value which we want to store
get error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="grdstock" runat="server" alignment="right"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4"
        EnableModelValidation="True"  ForeColor="Black"  CellSpacing="2" onselectedindexchanged="grdstock_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dry">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: Right">
          <asp:Label ID="lblDry" runat="server" CssClass="colHeader-RightAlign" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text=''
            <%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Dry_Diff").ToString()) ?  "" :  string.Format("{0:0.00}",Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Dry_Diff").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Green">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: Right">
          <asp:Label ID="lblGreen" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text=''
            <%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Green_Diff").ToString()) ?  "" :  string.Format("{0:0.00}",Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Green_Diff").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Concentrat">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: Right">
          <asp:Label ID="lblConcentrat" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Larger" Text=''
            <%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Concentrat_Diff").ToString()) ?  "" :  string.Format("{0:0.00}",Convert.ToDouble(Eval("Concentrat_Diff").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</Gridview>
```

```cs
GridViewRow row = grdstock.SelectedRow;
// And you respective cell's value
dr = float.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);
gr = float.Parse(row.Cells[2].Text);
conc = float.Parse(row.Cells[3].Text);

if ((float)dr >= float.Parse(txtdry.Text) || (float)gr >= float.Parse(txtgreen.Text) || conc >= float.Parse(txtconcent.Text))
{
```

Comment: You could provide a little more details: Which error are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row.Cells[1].Text will be empty as the grid column is defined as TemplateField and not as BoundField. So we need to access the control using FindControl and retrieve the text from it. Try the below code.

```
    Label lblTmp;
    lblTmp = row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblDry") as Label;
    if (lblTmp != null)
        dr = float.Parse(lblTmp.Text);

    lblTmp = row.Cells[2].FindControl("lblGreen") as Label;
    if (lblTmp != null)
        gr = float.Parse(lblTmp.Text);

    lblTmp = row.Cells[3].FindControl("lblConcentrat") as Label;
    if (lblTmp != null)
        conc = float.Parse(lblTmp.Text);
```

Comment: hell sir ,i get error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In which line, you are getting the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: GridViewRow row = grdstock.SelectedRow;

Comment: Above mentioned line does not seems to be a problem.                       
    protected void grdstock_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = grdstock.SelectedRow;

Comment: i have mention this protected void grdstock_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { GridViewRow row = grdstock.SelectedRow;}   but error occure on line  lblTmp = row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblDry") as Label;   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: It seems lblDry is not present in Cells[1]. Cross check in which column it is present and provide the value accordingly.